# Сделать избранное для пользователя

Tags: javascript, php, html

Всем доброго времени суток. Для сайта понадобилась функция "Добавить в избранное". Суть работы: пользователь авторизуется(использовал сессии), после заходит на страницу с записями. Возле каждой записи есть картинка (звездочка пустая). При нажатии на нее должна обязательно изменится картинка (звездочка желтая) и, соответственно, добавить эту запись в избранное(другая страница). При переходе на страницу с избранным, должны отображаться эти записи. И они должны отображаться для каждого юзера свои. Изначально ни одна запись не добавлена в избранное. Желательно, что бы после выхода, пользователь мог зайти и все избранные сохранились. Если есть советы по реализации - буду очень рад их лицезреть, т.к. скоро дедлайн... Буду рад любой помощи. Спасибо.

*Дополнительный вопрос: пытался реализовать с помощью js пару фишек, но скрипты не работают. Как бы не пытался. Работаю с OpenServer, до этого с js не работал. Если кто сталкивался, отпишите в комментарии. Спасибо

Comment: Создаёте ajax запрос с номером товара и отсылаете на обработчик php, заносите в базу данных где у каждого пользователя свои товары. Как бы логика составлена, необходимо добавить условий и небольших уведомлений, о том что товар добавлен в избранное.

Comment: @MoloF Спасибо за ответ. Я, как новичок, еще не работал с ajax и хотелось бы реализовать на php(и/или js, но он не работает)

Comment: Ну реализуйте на php, в чем проблема? Звездочка будет кнопкой сабмита формы, после сабмита возвращаетесь на ту же страницу.

Comment: Не могу толком ничего придумать, хелп ми, гайз...

Comment: что за проблемы такие с js и ajax? вот примитивный обработчик (на самом деле так не нужно делать, просто как пример)
`document.querySelectorAll('.add2fav').forEach(element => {
    element.onclick = function(){
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '/add2fav?id='+element.getAttribute(id4fav), false);
        xhr.send();
    }
});`